# Що таке "димогон" та "кобильниця"?

Tags: значення-слів

Читаю переклад "Воно" Стівена Кінга:

*Приблизно на третій чверті шляху вздовж кварталу, якщо прямувати в бік перехрестя і мертвого світлофора, автомобільний рух по Вітчем-стрит було перегороджено **димогонами** й чотирма помаранчевого кольору **кобильницями**.*

І одразу ж виникло два питання: "Що таке димогони (які вони дими ганяють на вулиці під час дощу та повені)? Що таке кобилиці?". На жаль пошуки в Інтернеті не дали ніяких результатів. В СУМі слова "димогон" немає, однак, там є [кобильниця](http://sum.in.ua/s/kobyljnyci):

> Колода на чотирьох похилих ніжках, що використовується в парі з іншою
>   як підставка для чого-небудь (якщо перейти на слово "козла").

Проте, мені все ще незрозуміло, що це, тому, можливо, у цього слова є якісь сучасніші синоніми. А також буду дуже вдячний за фото, якщо це можливо, і димогона, і кобильниці.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пан вказав, шчо то єсьть перекладом, отже спочатку на [першоџерело](https://okdownloads.cc/download/It_%20A%20Novel/It_%20A%20Novel%20-%20Stephen%20King.pdf#page=12):

> About three-quarters of the way down the block as one headed toward the
> intersection and the dead traffic light, Witcham Street was blocked to motor
> traffic by [smudgepots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smudge_pot) and four orange [sawhorses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawhorse).

Загалом *кобильниця,* шчо може бути і як [козла для пиляня дров](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), є влучним словом зі значінями:

> A *saw-horse* or *sawhorse* (*saw-buck*, *trestle*, *buck*) is a beam with four legs used to support a board or plank for sawing.
>
> ---
>
> 2. Колода на чотирьох похилих ніжках, що використовується в парі з іншою як підставка для чого-небудь; кобилиця (у 2 знач.).
> 3. Підставка для різання дров, що складається зі збитих навхрест жердин, з'єднаних поперечкою.

Про *smudgepots*:

> A *smudge pot* (also known as a *choofa* or *orchard heater*) is an oil-burning device used to prevent frost on fruit trees.
>
> *оліјепальниј рушіј для запобіганя инію в саду* (приблизниј переклад)

Сєбто таке собі багатє, але дешчо рушіјове, кероване (не дуже, оскільки є згадка про »багато диму«) і котре гріє саду.  Переклад відносно підходить, але може визвати, так, деякого нерозуміня.